# Sum roll of a metric for different groups in R

Tags: r

I have monthly sales data for different cities, and I would like to roll them up on 3 month sum basis.

```
Month, City, Sales
Jan, Paris, 1000
Jan, NY , 2000
feb, Paris , 1200
Feb, NY, 3000
Mar, Paris, 1000
Mar, NY, 2000
April, Paris, 1400
April, NY, 1000
May, Paris, 2000
May, NY, 1000
```

Now, I would like the sum of last 3 months as an output for each month and city as below.

```
Month, City, Sales,  R3Month
Jan, Paris, 1000 , 1000
Jan, NY , 2000 , 2000
feb, Paris , 1300 , 2300
Feb, NY, 3000 , 5000
Mar, Paris, 1000 , 3300
Mar, NY, 2000 , 7000
April, Paris, 1400, 3700
April, NY, 1000 , 6000
May, Paris, 2000, 4400
May, NY, 1000 , 4000
```

Any leads would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `ave` to group by City and rollapplyr to do the actual rolling sum.  `partial=TRUE` causes it to use partial sums for the first two months of each City.

```
library(zoo)

roll <- function(x) rollapplyr(x, 3, sum, partial = TRUE)
transform(DF, R3Month = ave(Sales, City, FUN = roll))
```

giving:

```
   Month  City Sales R3Month
1    Jan Paris  1000    1000
2    Jan    NY  2000    2000
3    feb Paris  1300    2300
4    Feb    NY  3000    5000
5    Mar Paris  1000    3300
6    Mar    NY  2000    7000
7  April Paris  1400    3700
8  April    NY  1000    6000
9    May Paris  2000    4400
10   May    NY  1000    4000
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- "
Month, City, Sales
Jan, Paris, 1000
Jan, NY , 2000
feb, Paris , 1300
Feb, NY, 3000
Mar, Paris, 1000
Mar, NY, 2000
April, Paris, 1400
April, NY, 1000
May, Paris, 2000
May, NY, 1000"
DF <- read.csv(text = Lines, as.is = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)
```

Comment: `df %>% 
  group_by(City) %>%
  mutate(R3Month = rollapplyr(Sales, 3, sum, partial = TRUE))` should also do.